# Why is my image request undefined in my Vue.js Nuxt app

Tags: javascript, database, vue.js, nuxt.js, strapi

I can't figure out why my nuxt app isn't pulling images from my database. I have a list component and separate component for the list items which iterates over project in my project list.

I can pull all other data through like project names, summaries without issue but although I've added images for each project in my Strapi database I can't seem to get the data. I ran a GraphQL query to double check the JSON data which confirms the images are attached to the projects, for example:

```
 {
    "id": "2",
    "Name": "Kīpuka",
    "image": [
      {
        "url": "/uploads/190217_KIPUKA_Editorial_Mockup_paas_e2e1316f4c.jpeg"
      }
    ]
  },
```

I am trying to pull the images into my app like this; I'm trying to bind the image source so for every project it shows the respective image.

```
  <ul :key="project.id">
   <img class="hover-preview" :src="'https://localhost:1337/' + project.image.url" alt="">
   </ul>
```

The images do not load and the network window shows the request is undefined.

```
 "Request URL:https://localhost:1337/undefined"
```

I'm not sure why it can't find the url since it is passed using "project.image.url", I had a look at other questions on Stack Overflow but I couldn't find an answer that seems to fix my issues, any help would be really appreciate as I've hit a wall with this and can't progress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`image` in your JSON is an array of images. To get the first image you'd have to use `project.image[0].url`.

I'd even add a function to construct that url for you instead of concatenating the strings in your template.
For example:

In your template:

```
<ul :key="project.id">
  <img class="hover-preview" :src="buildImageUrl(project.image[0].url)" alt="">
</ul>
```

In your methods:

```js
buildImageUrl(image) {
  if (!image) return "path/to/fallback/image.jpg";
  return `https://localhost:1337/${image}`
}
```

EDIT:
Updated your codesandbox. It's a lot to recall here. Take a close look at how I handled your JSON and compare it with your initial codesandbox.
https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-montalcini-nmmv3?file=/src/components/ProjectItem.vue

Keep in mind that the giphy links you chose aren't the actual .gif URLs. Right-click on the gif and copy it's actual address. the URL has to end with `.gif`.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I tried doing this but unfortunately receive an 'Cannot read property 'url' of undefined' error each time

Comment: are you using a v-for to iterate through your data? Your example didn't show that. If possible, can you create a codesandbox with your example? Doesn't have to be fully connected to a API. Just throw in your example JSON as data. But it helps massively in debugging the issue

Comment: I have tried to set up a codesandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-sea-nwu0d)  to show you how my list / components are set up although I can't get it to read any local JSON data but it should show you the structure of what I am attemptoing. It's my first time using codesandbox and vue.js so apologies for these issues, and thanks very much for all your help so far.

Comment: I wasn't checking the image arrays for null, so if a database entry had no images attached it would throw an undefined exception during iteration over the database items. Ensuring the database proejcts have entries and adding a null check to my code have fixed this.